# Can't generate Birt report because command line or file name is too long?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, birt

Im trying to create a Groovy script to output a Birt report to Html. When I attemp to run my script I get `Command line is too long. In order to reduce its length classpath file can be used. Would you like to enable classpath file mode for all run configurations of your project?`

I enabled classpath file mode and now I'm getting `Error running generatePerformanceReport: Cannot run program "C:\DevTools\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java" (in directory "C:\Projects\web-tests\src\test\groovy"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long`

What filename or extension is too long?

Here is my groovy script (generatePerformanceReport.groovy)

```
import org.eclipse.birt.core.exception.BirtException;
import org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.Platform;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineConfig;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.HTMLRenderOption;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IReportRunnable;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IRunAndRenderTask;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.PDFRenderOption;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngine;

String reportDesign = "C:\\DevTools\\birtReports\\report.rptdesign"
try {
  EngineConfig config = new EngineConfig();

  Platform.startup(config);

  ReportEngine engine = new ReportEngine(config);

  IReportRunnable reportRunnable = engine.openReportDesign(reportDesign);
  IRunAndRenderTask runAndRender = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(reportRunnable);

  HTMLRenderOption option = new PDFRenderOption();
  option.setOutputFileName("C:\\web-tests\\report.html");
  option.setOutputFormat("HTML");
  runAndRender.setRenderOption(option);

  runAndRender.run();

  runAndRender.close();
  engine.destroy();
  Platform.shutdown();
} catch (EngineException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (BirtException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You need to show the `classpath` that you are using instead of your class.

Comment: how do i view the classpath?